Storing occupancy grids locally for later use
I would like to know if there is any standard way of storing occupancy grids and other mapping formats for usage in later simulations or runs of the system. I have explored using ros bags and just using naive approaches (for example, for an occupancy grid this would be text or csv file where each cell is represented in its row,column pair), but I would like to know if there are any standard practices.

Sounds like you need the map saver. Details here.
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_map_server/README.md
Mark
